# The video file cannot be played (on Galaxy S)

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, video, media-player

Last few days my video files cannot be played on my Samsung Galaxy S and I do not know why.

I select a video and I choce to wath it with the android's video player and I have the message below :
"The video file cannot be played"

Have you a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the issue with files, that you were previously able to play, try to reboot your phone. If playback works afterwards, you seem to have the same issue as described in this problem: [Unsupported File Type: Why did my Samsung Galaxy S suddenly stop supporting MP3s?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/samsung-galaxy-s-unsupported-file-type-mp3)

I do not know of a fix for this yet, the only workaround seems to be a reboot.

Comment: Thanks. A simple reboot has solved my problem. I don't know why I had not thought of earlier.
(maybe because I do not associate Unix and Reboot =) )

Comment: If you have the same problem as me, this will unfortunately occur every 2-3 days :(. If you are able to reproduce this behaviour at will, I would be happy to know how you do it, so I can try it myself and perhaps find out what is causing it.

Comment: No problem. 
But it's the first time and, I hope, the last..

Answer (score 1):

Android's built in decoders are rather picky about the files they will play - limited encoded resolution (possibly less than that of the device's display), limited bitrate, limited formats.

If these are new files, try encoding them to be less demanding.

If these are files that used to work, see if something on the phone is perhaps slowing it down - on on rare occasion I had a file that generally plays start failing part way through.  A reboot might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HTC Desire which had the same problem. A simple reboot did not solve the problem but when I shut it down, removed the battery, reinserted the battery after waiting about 10 minutes and then restarting the phone the problem was corrected. My problem affected gallery and all the browsers. I presume they all use the same engine for displaying video.